# Adicionar loader no ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como posso adicionar um loader na requisição do meu ajax?

```
$(document).on('click', '#reg-discagem input[type="submit"]', function(e){

                  e.preventDefault(); 
var form = $('#reg-discagem');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'EnviarPedidoChamada.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize() 
            })
            .done(function(data){
                $('#form-content_discagem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#form-content_discagem').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                });
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
            });
});
```

Comment: coloque o html do seu formulário. assim fica um pouco mais fácil responder a pergunta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Consegui desta forma em minha aplicação.

http://blog.astraube.eti.br/2012/04/exibir-loading-nas-requisicoes-ajax/

Comment: O ideal seria responder a pergunta aqui mesmo. O link pode vir a quebrar.

Answer (score 2):

Usando ajax é mais dificil mesmo, eu particulamente prefiro usar o jquery form

Esse é o link da documentação

https://github.com/jquery-form/form

O código para enviar, ficaria assim...

```
$('#material_form').ajaxForm({

  beforeSend: function() {        
     // $("#material_form").fadeOut(0);
     // $("#carregando_envio_material").fadeIn(0);
     // $("#progresso_envio_mateial").html("0%");
     //$("#msg_erro_envia_material").html("");    
  },
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {

  //aqui fica a % do load.... voce pode dar o fadin e fad outa nas divs para 

  //aparecer so a partocentagem
  //$("#progresso_envio_mateial").html(percentComplete+"%");
  console.log(percentComplete);

  },
  success: function() {

  },
  complete: function(xhr) {

    //status.html(xhr.responseText);
    data = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(data);


    if(data == "sucesso"){

    }else{

    }
  }
});
```

qualquer coisa, se essa não for a documentação correta
esse é o link do meu escript
http://b1.alunoativo.com.br/publico/js/sistema/jquery.form.js

copia o codigo e cria a nos seus arquivos que vai fucionar